# state update in pinia is not reflecting in template

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia, vue-reactivity

state.ts

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
   import { ref, reactive, computed } from "vue";

export const useStateStore = defineStore("state", () => {
  const state = ref<string>('first');

  function setState(step: string): void {
    state.value = step;
    console.log('state', state)
  }

  function isState(step: string): boolean {
    return state.value === step;
  }


  return { state, setState, isState };
});
```

template.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Other from './other.vue';
import { useStateStore } from '../../stores/state';
const { state, isState, setState } = useStateStore()
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <span>{{state}}</span>
    <Other />
  </div>
</template>
```

other.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { useStateStore } from '../../stores/state';
    const { state, isState, setState } = useStateStore()
</script>
<template>
    <button @click="setState('second')">change state</button>
</template>
```

on clicking change state button in other.vue state value is getting update in pinia but not reflected in template.vue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `storeToRefs`. More can be read [here](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/) in the pinia docs.